# What is the default order for sort?

Tags: shell, sorting, unix

Given(a.txt):

```
2n 
4t 
7t 
11t
```

After:

```
sort a.txt
```

OutPut:

```
11t 
2n 
4t 
7t
```

**Question:**

why is this order? what is the sort based on? 
(number or other?)

And when i try to give this input:

```
2
4
7
11
20
30
```

Output give me this order:

```
11
2
20
30
4
7
```

So confused, why is 11 always the 1st?

Comment: Check `man sort`.

Comment: I did, but still really confused, could i get any explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man sort`:

> The sort utility sorts text and binary files by lines.  A line is a
>   record separated from the subsequent record by a newline (default) or
>   NUL '\0' character (-z option).  A record can contain any printable or
>   unprintable characters.  Comparisons are based on one or more sort
>   keys extracted from each line of input, and are performed
>   **lexicographically**, according to the current locale's collating rules
>   and the specified command-line options that can tune the actual
>   sorting behavior.  By default, if keys are not given, sort uses entire
>   lines for comparison.

`sort` is using alphabetical ([lexicographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)) order by default.  If you want your file to be sorted numerically, use `sort -n`.

Regarding your specific question about why 11 is coming before 2 in the sorted output:

- lexicographically, any string starting with 1 will always be less than any string that starts with 2
- sort is not using numeric order by default

You can [see](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92447/201820) the ASCII values of 1 and 2:

```
printf '%d\n' "'1" "'2"
49
50
```

Comment: sorry, i am confused, but why give input:2
4
7
11
20
30 output: 11 still always the 1st

Answer (score 0):

[GNU sort manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html#FOOT1) says:

> all comparisons use the character collating sequence specified by the **LC_COLLATE** locale.

you can type `locale | grep LC_COLLATE` to check your `LC_COLLATE`. If output is `en_US.UTF-8`, `sort` usually sorts different lines based on the value of **ascii** by default.

For the `a.txt` you mention above, `sort` will compare the **first character of lines**. While the ascii value of `1` is 49, `2` is 50 and so on, it turns out that 11t is before 2n because the ascii value of `1` is smaller than that of `2`.

If you want to compare numerically only, try `-n`. If compared alphanumerically, try `-d`. You can learn those options deeply in `man sort`.